# Understanding alpha mask in Android

Tags: android

I am learning how to use Shaders and trying to understand an [old post by Romain Guy](http://www.curious-creature.com/2012/12/13/android-recipe-2-fun-with-shaders/) on BitmapShader. In the post, there is a demo video on what he is trying to achieve, with all the source code. He is using an blur image like this :

[image]

Looking at the mask image, it seems it has alpha 1 at center and 0 as we move out. This should imply that as the image zooms out, this overlay mask would hide everything beneath it because of it's opacity. But the opposite is happening.

I am unable to understand how is this mask creating an effect as if mask center has alpha 0.

Related code from the post :

```
package com.example.spotlight;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener;

public class SpotlightView extends View {
    private int mTargetId;

    private Bitmap mMask;
    private float mMaskX;
    private float mMaskY;
    private float mMaskScale;
    private Matrix mShaderMatrix = new Matrix();

    private Bitmap mTargetBitmap;
    private final Paint mPaint = new Paint();

    private AnimationSetupCallback mCallback;

    public interface AnimationSetupCallback {
        void onSetupAnimation(SpotlightView spotlight);
    }

    public SpotlightView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.SpotlightView, 0, 0);
        try {
            mTargetId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.SpotlightView_target, 0);

            int maskId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.SpotlightView_mask, 0);
            mMask = convertToAlphaMask(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), maskId));

            android.util.Log.d("Spotlight", "c=" + mMask.getConfig());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            android.util.Log.e("Spotlight", "Error while creating the view:", e);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    public float getMaskScale() {
        return mMaskScale;
    }

    public void setMaskScale(float maskScale) {
        mMaskScale = maskScale;
        invalidate();
    }

    public float getMaskX() {
        return mMaskX;
    }

    public void setMaskX(float maskX) {
        mMaskX = maskX;
        invalidate();
    }

    public float getMaskY() {
        return mMaskY;
    }

    public void setMaskY(float maskY) {
        mMaskY = maskY;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        float maskW = mMask.getWidth() / 2.0f;
        float maskH = mMask.getHeight() / 2.0f;

        float x = mMaskX - maskW * mMaskScale;
        float y = mMaskY - maskH * mMaskScale;

        mShaderMatrix.setScale(1.0f / mMaskScale, 1.0f / mMaskScale);
        mShaderMatrix.preTranslate(-x, -y);

        mPaint.getShader().setLocalMatrix(mShaderMatrix);

        canvas.translate(x, y);
        canvas.scale(mMaskScale, mMaskScale);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mMask, 0.0f, 0.0f, mPaint);
    }

    public void setAnimationSetupCallback(AnimationSetupCallback callback) {
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                createShader();
                setMaskScale(1.0f);

                if (mCallback != null) {
                    mCallback.onSetupAnimation(SpotlightView.this);
                }

                getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });
    }

    private void createShader() {
        View target = getRootView().findViewById(mTargetId);
        mTargetBitmap = createBitmap(target);
        Shader targetShader = createShader(mTargetBitmap);
        mPaint.setShader(targetShader);
    }

    private static Shader createShader(Bitmap b) {
        return new BitmapShader(b, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    }

    private static Bitmap createBitmap(View target) {
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(target.getWidth(), target.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        target.draw(c);
        return b;
    }

    private static Bitmap convertToAlphaMask(Bitmap b) {
        Bitmap a = Bitmap.createBitmap(b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(a);
        c.drawBitmap(b, 0.0f, 0.0f, null);
        return a;
    }

    public float computeMaskScale(float d) {
        // Let's assume the mask is square
        return d / (float) mMask.getHeight();
    }
}
```

Comment: The center of the mask is fully transparent (alpha 0%), and it becomes darker as you move away from the center (alpha 100%). What do you mean the opposite happens?

Comment: @cricket_007 : I guess that's the point of confusion. How did you know center of mask is fully transparent ? To me it looked like it's fully opaque. Sorry for this naive question !

Comment: I think I see your confusion, but it's just an alpha channel mask. I've made them with photoshop, and that's just how those work. I'm not too familiar with what the code is doing, but something in the `convertToAlphaMask` method would be determining how that image is displayed

Comment: Thank you. I just checked the image in photoshop, and confirmed what you mentioned.